# Laravel Eloquent Batch Saving

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

is there any way on how to save a Whole batch of file using eloquent ? 
For example I have a 1000 items to be saved, The traditional way is using foreach and saving it.

What I foresee is if the internet connection is down during the middle of the saving process, the remainder of the items that still not done will not be save, is there any way to address this issue ?

What I think feasible is using stored procedure but the bandwidth will kill us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is **transaction**, please take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#database-transactions.

> You may use the transaction method on the DB facade to run a set of operations within a database transaction. If an exception is thrown within the transaction Closure, the transaction will automatically be rolled back. If the Closure executes successfully, the transaction will automatically be committed.

Another way is using the [insert()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#inserts) function to create data at once.

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
  ['email' => 'taylor@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
  ['email' => 'dayle@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
]);
```